# Django/S3/Boto: How do I encrypt files?

Tags: django, encryption, amazon-s3, boto

With the "raw" Django S3 Boto API there is a `key.set_contents_from_file` method which can take an `encrypt_key=True` argument to make it so that your data is stored in an encrypted format in S3.  I'd like to get this same functionality, but use the (more convenient) S3BotoStorage (which you can use with a normal Django FileField).  Unfortunately though I can't seem to find any equivalent of `encrypt_key` for S3BotoStorage; am I missing something, or can the storage not encrypt files?

Comment: You can now do that by setting `AWS_S3_ENCRYPTION=True` in you settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open pull request to add this functionality to the `S3BotoStorage` https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/pull-request/17/include-support-for-s3s-server-side but it does not exist in any currently released version.